# Unexpected result when I comparing two file to report the difference between them

Tags: python

I´m working with two text files that are similar but not the same.

File 1:

```
GCF_000739415.1
GCF_001263815.1
GCF_001297745.1
...
```

File 2:

```
GCA_000739415.1
GCA_001263815.1
...
```

Here, I´m looking for a specific pattern to differentiate them, his name is ID.
For example, ID´ file 1: GCF_000739415.1, GCF_001263815.1, GCF_001297745.1
ID´file 2: GCA_000739415.1, GCA_001263815.1
The only difference between IDs is GCF versus GCA, this difference it´s only for the database where they come from, but the numbers are the same.
However, file 2 has not GCF_001297745.1 version (GCA_001297745.1), so my goal is to report what IDs are not in both files.
For example, "GC*_001297745.1 is not in the file 2"

With these in mind, I´m using this code:

```
with open("assembly_summary_genbank.txt", 'r') as f_1:
    contents_1 = f_1.readlines()
with open("assembly_summary_refseq.txt", 'r') as f_2:
    contents_2 = f_2.readlines()

# PART 2: Search for IDs
matches_1 = re.findall("GCF_[0-9]*\.[0-9]", str(contents_1))
matches_2 = re.findall("GCA_[0-9]*\.[0-9]", str(contents_2))
#print(matches_1)
for match in matches_1:
    if match not in matches_2:
        print(f"{match} is not in both files")
```

My unexpected result is this:

```
GCF_000739415.1 is not in both files
GCF_001263815.1 is not in both files
GCF_001297745.1 is not in both files
```

When I need something like this:

```
GC*_001297745.1 is not in both files
```

I put * in the third character (F or A) because this is a difference that doesn't matter. I´m looking for IDs that are not in both files, any comment to fix this unexpected result is welcome.

Comment: You could make the GCF/GCA part of the pattern a *lookbehind assertion*, so that it doesn't become part of the matched text.

Comment: Could you give me an example @jasonharper? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add capture groups to the regexes so that the `GCF_` and `GCA_` are not part of the results but do help in the search.

```
matches_1 = set(re.findall("GCF_([0-9]*\.[0-9])", str(contents_1)))
matches_2 = set(re.findall("GCA_([0-9]*\.[0-9])", str(contents_2)))
for match in matches_1:
    if match not in matches_2:
        print(f"GC*_{match} is not in both files")
```

Output

```
GC*_001297745.1 is not in both files
```

I also made the results sets to avoid duplicates. With them being sets, you can:

```
for match in matches_1.symmetric_difference(matches_2):
    print(f"GC*_{match} is not in both files")
```

Which I think will produce a better result since your `for` loop only finds items from `contents_1` that are not in `contents_2` but not items that are in `contents_2` but not in `contents_1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you see here it actually includes the 'GCA' / 'GCF' at the start so they will never be the same.

match (starting GCF): `GCF_000739415.1`

matches_2 (all starting GCA): `['GCA_000739415.1', 'GCA_001263815.1']`

You will need to take out the GCF/GCA and then compare